# Is a lightweight VM OS possible?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 and spend about an even amount of time between the two.

I found myself wishing there was something that wouldn't need a restart but didn't have the large overhead of virtualization from within a full OS.

In other words, is something like a small footprint OS that just switches between Ubuntu and Windows possible or would it still run as slowly as for instance Ubuntu on Windows Hyper-V?

I tried Hyper-V with a dedicated drive, but that didn't quite feel like a full-fledged OS due to a number of reasons one being as far as I know, it is not possible to utilize my graphics card from ubuntu within Hyper-V.

Comment: Very little overhead in the virtualization. The only problem is the virtualization of specific devices, in particular graphics cards, that are never fully supported. If you have only one OS that requires a complete graphics card (games in Windows, or AI training on Linux), use it as a the host and put the other one in a VM. If you need graphics in both, continue dual-booting, or get a 2nd computer:)

Comment: One requires a full graphics card, the other requires direct access to the network adapter rather than being connected to a virtual adapter. I gave up setting up the virtualized adapter with docker as that proved to be too large of a headache.

Comment: *"the other requires direct access to the network adapter"*? Why so?

Comment: I suppose "requires" may have been too strong of a word. Rather, docker port publishing to the host OS was not working on the virtual adapter, so I had to view my app through the virtualized firefox/chrome. The experience itself of ubuntu under windows hyperv was also laggy w/o hardware acceleration. Also worth mentioning: I tried docker with wsl2 which was my original plan but ran into port mapping issues there.